# why console.log and document.write giving different output for the same code?

Tags: javascript, dom, console.log

Following are code with output

```
var myArray = ["one", "two","three", "four"];
var arr = [myArray];
console.log(arr);               //ouput - [Array[4]]
window.document.write(arr);     //ouput - one,two,three,four
```

Why both line gives different output?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `document.write` calls the `toString` method, wheras console is a vendor styled thing.

Comment: You could at least try to make it look like you searched on google before coming here to ask

Answer (score 3):

`console.log` will know the structure of Array or Object or any javascript data.
So it print it properly.

```
console.log(myArray) //  ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

While, [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) will call [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method on it`(arr)`.So it print `one,two,three,four`

```
window.document.write(arr.toString() // one,two,three,four
```

Answer (score 0):

document.write() calls the toString() on the array.

You can use array.toString() for the same result